# Calling JWT protected Api with a cookie

Tags: authentication, cookies, web, jwt

I've got an SPA with an Web Api back end. The api calls are authenticated with JWT in headers. The problem I'm trying to solve is how to make one particular api call  not with XHR but using `window.open`. I've sort of solved this by saving a token to a cookie prior to the call and creating a middleware which intercepts this cookie for just one route and puts it to headers. So that JWT auth middleware can do its' thing. This Api call is a GET route so I'm not concerned with XSR issues.
Could there be any other gotchas with this "hack"?

**A bit of a background**:
The api call is sending back a pdf stream. I can open it in a new tab, no problem. But then I face all sorts of browser specific issues - Edge/IE do not allow opening blobs; Chrome, Safari need a setting to allow popups... and there is a chance of an AdBlock presence. Popup blocking also comes in with FileSaver.js. On the other hand, just opening a Url works everywhere with no exceptions. With the audience (computer illiterate mostly) I'm targeting this seems like the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you handle that route on your SPA. And make an XHR request from frontend rather than handle it directly by API backend.

Comment: May be a bit of background will make it clearer. I added that to the question

Comment: I see. I think in your case it would be a much better solution to pass an access token with url parameters.